# Can you get a type dependency tree from the Typescript compiler?

Tags: typescript

Can Typescript generate and output a dependency tree of types in a script?

For example, given these types:

```js
type Point = {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

type Line {
  start: Point;
  end: Point;
}

type Shape {
  lines: Line[];
}
```

`Shape` depends on `Line`, which depends on `Point`, which depends only on primitives.

During type checking `tsc` must build a structure that represents these dependencies, and I'm hoping to get access to it so I can chart and visualize it.

I know there is a compiler API, but can't find much documentation on it outside of this intro: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API

Other tools I'm finding like [madge](https://github.com/pahen/madge) are more focused on file import dependencies, which is useful, but doesn't go as far as I'm hoping to get.

Comment: since typescript uses duck typing i don't think you will be able to find exactly what you are looking for. `Line` depends on an object that *looks like* `Point` but doesn't necessarily have to be a `Point`, it just has to have two properties `x` and `y` that are of type `number`. The only thing that says `Shape` depends on `Line` which depends on `Point` would be the file the types are declared in

Comment: @about14sheep yeah, I was a little afraid of that